# Share domain data between usecases using android clean architecture

Tags: android, static, system.reactive, rx-java2, clean-architecture

Where should I save the domain data instances in an android clean architecture project? How to make the instances accessible by all the usecases without breaking the following dependency rule:

> source code dependencies can only point inwards and nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle.

Currently, we're using static data but we're having issues with the static data being lost when the os kills the process (when the application is in the background).

I read the answers to the following question [losing reference to static data in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701197/losing-reference-to-static-data-in-android-studio), and it suggests that if you have a state that you wish to preserve, you will need to persist it to disk using shared preferences or a serialized file stream.

Is there a better way to share business logic data between different usecases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approach would be

- have some domain object representing the state in entities circle
- define an IRepository in usecase circle for the domain object
- have a repository implementation in the interface adapters circle which handles persistence if the domain object

With that separation dependency rule remains intact